# What is the difference between "as a result" and "with the aid" in this context?

Tags: differences

> "The Golden Gate Bridge in San Francisco achieved worldwide fame almost immediately after its completion in 1937, not just because it was a technical masterpiece but also **as a result**/**with the aid** of its elegant design."

Why is *"as a result"* the right answer according to the answer key? Why can't both work?

Comment: "with the aid of" is not generally associated with things but with people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

' ... achieved worldwide fame almost immediately after its completion in 1937 with the aid of its elegant design.' works.

But there would be a semantic imbalance between 'not just because of A but also with the aid of B'. Whereas 'not just because of A but also as a result of B' preserves symmetry.